# How to modify Sequelize query to not send ID on row creation?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, sequelize.js

I want to give a row a primary key that is a UUID in Postgres. I have the Postgres side working and the default is set to `generate_uuid_v4()` on my primary key. If I manually send the SQL through `psql` it works. However, Sequelize is sending the id with a value of NULL when I create a new row. Is there a way to stop Sequelize from doing this?

I am also using Sequelize with `sequelize-typescript`, if that has anything to do with it.

This is the query that is being sent:
`INSERT INTO "User" ("id","firstName","lastName","middleInitial") VALUES (NULL,'Davis','Kimoto','S') RETURNING *;` The id value that is set to NULL needs to be eliminated. Is there a way I can tell Sequelize to never set or modify the id value?

Comment: Please share the model code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add to your model `defaultValue`:

`defaultValue: sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v4()')`

Comment: That ended up being the way to do it, but something was sending the id as NULL (which you can see in my query above). I don't know if that was done by vanilla Sequelize or sequelize-typescript, I haven't taken the time to figure that out. I wrote hooks for before update and before create that remove the id from the queries and that seems to work.